# Using Google Charts inside web app

Tags: javascript, charts

I'm building a web application using jQueryMobile and Google charts. I'm new to both, so be patient, please!
My problem is, I want to load the chart inside my application, but the request to Google forces a page refresh. In my app, i hide the address bar using "apple-mobile-web-app-capable", but when the chart loads, the address bar appears again. Is there any way I can load the chart without having to show the address bar in mobile devices? I tried with data-ajax="true", but it doesn´t work.

Comment: What code are you using for your AJAX?

Comment: $.ajax({
 url: url,
 dataType:"json",
 async: false
 })

Comment: Your question seems to be less about "Using Google Charts inside web app" and more about how to "Hide address bar on mobile device on AJAX all," correct?  You should probably edit the question and add tags for mobile devices.